# how to fetch row on the basis of json data stored in a column in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this

```
| is_selcted_cours   | content                                     | value |
|   (boolean)        |(json)                                       |       |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    true   | {"date":"07-Apr-2020","amount":"5050","type":"CT"}    |   1    |
|    false  | {"date":"07-Jun-2020","amount":"50","type":"CT"}      |   1    |
|    true   | {"date":"10-Aug-2020","amount":"6050","type":"MT"}    |   1    |
|    false  | {"date":"07-Jun-2020","amount":"50","type":"CT"}      |   2    |
|    true   | {"date":"07-Apr-2020","amount":"5050","type":"GT"}    |   3    |
|    true   | {"date":"07-Apr-2020","amount":"5050","type":"GT"}    |   3    |
|    true   | {"date":"07-Apr-2020","amount":"5050","type":"GT"}    |   3    |
```

I want to fetch all duplicate row (here duplicate means rows containing `is_selcted_cours is true` and `the value of date, amount in the content column` have same value) like in this table selected rows will be  `1,5,6,7`

Comment: yes.. @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an EXISTS condition for that:

```
select d1.*
from data d1
where is_selcted_cours
and exists (select *
            from data d2
            where d1.content ->> 'date' = d2.content ->> 'date'
              and d1.content ->> 'amount' = d2.content ->> 'amount'
              and d2.is_selcted_cours = d1.is_selcted_cours
              and d1.id <> d2.id)
```

The `d1.id <> d2.id` is necessary to not compare a row with itself. `id` is assumed to be a primary (or unique) key column.

Comment: can you please help me with one more thing  the selected row  from the above query i wanted to update the selected row with value 5 except any one row of each group which have whicch have same date amount and is_selected_cours true